# JavaScript to upload to server

Tags: c#, javascript

I am writing an ASP.NET script to capture a signature, I want to save the file on the server side.

The following code is JavaScript for saving the file. But it does not allow me to save from browser disable by safety measure:

```
flags = 0x2481000; //SigObj.renderRelative | SigObj.outputFilename | SigObj.color32BPP | SigObj.encodeData
rc = sigCtl.Signature.RenderBitmap(filename, -160, -160, "image/bmp", 0.5, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, 0.0, 0.0, flags );
```

How can I upload via JavaScript or C#?

Comment: what do you mean "browser disable by safety measure"?

Comment: Which javascript library are you using? Where is the image being stored on the client? Is it inside a canvas?

Comment: the above code is used to run and save on the client. But when I use it in my html/javascript code I get  error. I cannot directly save . I need to write a method in jscript to execute the avove to save on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not find it to be overkill, for your uses, i suggest trying out https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, i do think it is possible to adapt for use with C#. There is quite an extensive documentation for the plugin.
It is based on jQuery UI.

Cheers Kalle